Understanding the the intuitive Euler method error and its implementation
I'm trying to understand the intuitive estimation of the euler error for integrating simple differential equation.
Im following the wikipedia explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Global_truncation_error
The LTE is defined as $LTE = y(t_0+h) - y_1 = \frac{1}{2}h^2y''(t_o) + O(h^3)$.
And the Global truncation error is the cumulative effect of the LTE on each step, so we may intuitively estimate it as:
$GAE = \sum LTE = \sum^n \frac{1}{2}h^2y''(t_o) + O(h^3)$, where $n$ is the number of steps until $t$ has been reached.
Instead of doing a sum, we may multiply the error times the number of steps $n$, which in turn depends on the time horizon and the time step $n = \frac{t - t_0}{h}$.
Therefore
$GAE = \frac{t - t_0}{h} * \left(\frac{1}{2}h^2y''(t_o) + O(h^3)\right) =  \frac{(t - t_0) }{2}hy''(t_o) + O(h^2)$.
So that means that if I were to integrate a simple differential equation with the Euler method, the final discrepancy between the true solution and the estimated solution will be proportional to $(t - t_0)$ and $h$.
So the longer the simulation goes on $(t-t_0)$, the bigger the error and the smaller the time step $(h)$, the smaller the error.
However, when implementing the method to solve the following differential equations:
$y' = \cos(t), \quad y' = y$, the expected error behaviour does not happen.
I provide the code:
def solve_euler_sin(t_max, h):
    t = 0
    xs = 0
    xr = 0
    x_r = []
    x_s = []
    while (t < t_max):
        x_r.append(xr)
        x_s.append(xs)
        xs = xs + h * np.cos(t)
        xr = np.sin(t)
        t += h
    return x_r, x_s


def solve_euler_exp(t_max, h):
    t = 0
    xs = 1
    xr = 1
    x_r = []
    x_s = []
    while (t < t_max):
        x_r.append(xr)
        x_s.append(xs)
        xs = xs + h * xs
        xr = np.exp(t)
        t += h
    return x_r, x_s

for time in [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]:
    xr,xs = solve_euler_sin(time, 0.01)
    print("Final error: ", np.abs(xr[-1] - xs[-1]))
print()
print()
print()
for time in [1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]:
    xr,xs = solve_euler_exp(time, 0.01)
    print("Final error: ", np.abs(xr[-1] - xs[-1]))

In the first case, $y' = \cos(y)$, where the solution is $y = sin(t)$, the error does not increase as the time horizon increases and the time step remains the same.
However, in the second equation, whose solution is $y = e^t$, the error does increase, but it grows way faster than proportional to $(t - t_0)$.
Am I missing something?
Thanks!
